# Understanding list identifiers in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

[Apple tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation):

> Lists work with identifiable data. You can make your data identifiable in one of two ways: by passing along with your data a key path to a property that uniquely identifies each element, or by making your data type conform to the Identifiable protocol.

I am curious what the implications are for lists that show items by design that are semantically "equal", creating duplicate rows that should behave in the same manner (i.e. both be deleted on removal by id). For instance:

```
List(["a", "b", "b", "c", "c"], id: \.self) { str in
  Text(str)
}
```

I think I saw some sources saying that each row must be uniquely identified. Is that really true or should it be identifi-*able*?

The code above doesn't seem to crash and works fine -- is it actually fine?

Comment: Why you want to have duplicate cells in List? \.self says each element in array is unique, but if you have duplicates swift will remove the very first duplicate value while performing deletion. So, if you delete last “C”, swift will remove second last “C”. To see better put one of the “b” at last, and try deleting. It will work fine, but wouldn't give you expected outcome.

Comment: I want to have duplicate cells to construct a hypothetical situation to understand id constraints in SwiftUI better, because the documentation doesn't make me feel like I really understand it.

Comment: You can think of a database example, say in one db table “User” you have 3 rows, 2 users have same Name. Now if you want to delete a user, obviously you wouldn't delete based on Name, but on some unique identifier (id) a PK which determine each record uniquely.

Comment: did my answer helped you?

Answer (score 1):

> The code above doesn't seem to crash and works fine -- is it actually
> fine?

**Yes!** Definitely, **List** and **ForEach** needs their item's be in some way identifiable. What does it means for us? That means we should provide unique items to List or ForEach! But you would say wait a moment I did not make my array or items unique, and instead of that I made even duplicate items as well, So why it does worked?

Well I would say you absolutely made all your items unique, in this way that only 1 of them exist not 2 or . . ., you would say how? the answer is in `id: \.self` when you use `id: \.self` term you are literally saying and conforming to Integer Indexing ID system from SwiftUI, with using `id: \.self`  SwiftUI understand that you are not going show a way for SwiftUI to understand which item is which, then it start to work by itself, and given an undercover id to your items.

So you can even delete the part of: `id: \.self` from your code, if you can show a way to SwiftUI to make your items Identifiable, the way that SwiftUI works in this case is awesome, when you remove `id: \.self` it starts analysing the type of item in your List/ForEach, then automatically goes to search identifiable protocol in that type, So that means your CustomType also should conform identifiable.

Let me gave you an example that we are going delete `id: \.self` and even making more duplicate and also deleting items, all would be identifiable.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var array: Array<String> = ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"]
    
    var body: some View {

        List(array) { item in
          Text(item)
        }
        
        Button("remove last item") {
            
            if array.count > 0 { array.remove(at: array.count - 1) }
            
        }
        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
        .font(Font.body.weight(Font.Weight.bold))
        
        
    }
}

extension String: Identifiable {
    
    public var id: UUID {
        get {
            return UUID()
        }
    }
    
}
```

[image]